# Connecting QGIS through to "Acquire " SQL database

Tags: qgis-3, sql-server

I have the connection working and have a list of tables but all are showing "no geometry"

There are tables with xyz coordinates available but are still showing "no geometry"

Is it an issue with my connecting end or does the SQL database need amending?

Comment: Do you have actual geometry columns in your tables?

Comment: Yes there ae xyz  fields in the tables but Q does not seem to recognize them as geometry

Comment: Geometry is a specific type, QGis has no way of knowing what xyz means

Comment: How do you add a specific geometry field into the sql database?

Comment: It's a type introduced by the spatial extension, I'm not a SQL server user so I can't help more than that